# Database instead SQLITE - C# Server

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have a system that basicly is a Poker Server made with C# + Pubnub API. I get the old source and I am improving all the code.
I don't know if the system will be a big system or just for home games purpose, but I don't like SQLITE to be a Poker Server, the reason is:
I will make a Signup system, website to that read Database data and some things like new and past tournaments, new and past cash games, new and past freerolls.
I was thinking:
What Free/OpenSource/Creative Commons or any "freedom" Database System I can use?

**I am asking for help to choose a good and fast Database System that I can implement and use for a long time.**

Thank you

Comment: Does it need to be relational? NoSQL an option?

Comment: PostgreSQL is free

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I want a relational. 
I was thinking about PostgreSQL but have a good support to C# (and maybe later a PHP website)?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you use PostgreSQL, then the .NET library for it is : http://www.npgsql.org/ It's the same like other SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with Microsoft's stack why not to use MS SQL Server Express? Suppose, it will feet all you needs, and it's free. Also if you are going to deploy your server on some hosting, migration from MS SQL Server Express to MS SQL Server will be easy.